# How to get vendor/bus type information about wifi card in /sys/class/net on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, filesystems

I have a c++ application, that runs on Ubuntu,  that when it starts up needs to parse /sys/class/net for all the wireless interfaces. I am currently able to find the names of the interfaces but I am trying to pull out either the vendor name or the type of bus that they are using in order to identify which interface belongs to which card.

I can get the vendor code from /sys/class/interface/phy80211/device/vendor. but that file is only there when the device is plugged in over the pci. If it is an external card then this file never appears. Is there a way to find this information that doesn't depend on if they are plugged in with usb or pci.